# nodej2 v20.1.0 - How to require Buffer and use buffer.Blob constructor?

Tags: node.js, blob

I am unable to use the constructor of [Blob class](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#class-blob) inside an old node application still using `require`.

The [page that illustrates Buffer and Blob](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) recommends to `import` Buffer, but does not provide any example of the syntax using `require`.

I have tried to use both `new buffer.Blob` (as indicated in the examples) `new Buffer.Blob` and `new Buffer.buffer.Blob`, but I always get the message that I am not invoking a constructor.

I've tried many sorts of `require`s so far:

```
const buffer = require('node:buffer');
const buffer = require('buffer');
```

I am using Node v20.1.0, but modifying the app to use `import` is not an option. I gotta stick to `require`.

How should I require the Blob class and use its constructor?

Comment: You have i already correct. `const buffer = require("buffer"); console.log(new buffer.Blob())` **must** work. Have you forgotten the parentheses?

Comment: @Marc - No. I haven't forgotten them. The fact that the errors messages I reported mention invocations should have told you that parentheses were provided; otherwise you woudn't have an invocation (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while looking for fixes for a similar issue (failing to find the `Buffer` definition) that I have been experiencing when developing a project based on Blockly. That setup uses a server called Webpack, and that actually gave me a useful error message (after several tries where the message was swallowed somewhere in the chain):

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in '/home/matej/proj/bob/iqblb/node_modules/apg-js/src/apg-api'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/") }'
    - install 'buffer'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "buffer": false }
```

Posting here in case it helps the posterity, whoever may run into similar issues in similar contexts.